# Linking a function to a command tag for a Button widget tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to link the function below to a button in my tkinter GUI, however I am having trouble, as the function doesn't execute on button press.

```
createFrame=tk.Frame(root)

def raiseFrame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()
```

I've tried:

```
createButton=tk.Button(treeviewFrame,text="Create",font=buttonFont,bg='blue',fg='lightblue',command=raiseFrame(createFrame))
```

and:

```
createButton=tk.Button(treeviewFrame,text="Create",font=buttonFont,bg='blue',fg='lightblue',command=lambda createFrame:raiseFrame)
```

Comment: Replace ur lambda with ```lambda: raiseFrame(createFrame)``` or use ```functools.partial```

Comment: Also read [Why is Button parameter “command” executed when declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-button-parameter-command-executed-when-declared) for a clearer explanation.